# How to add a plus button in a navigation bar when the edit button is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am writing a simple app with a TableView controller. This view has a navigation bar, and has an edit button. I would like add the plus button in the top left corner only when the content is being edited and the edit button has been pressed.

I added the button using the following prewritten code:

```
// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for
//this view controller.
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
```

I don't know if there is a method that is called when the edit button that was created is pressed, but I think that would solve this problem as I could simply created add the plus button in that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `setEditing:animated:` on your view controller. It'll get called everytime the editing state changes.

Make sure you call super first.